# Join 3 tables based on parent table column value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables

table x (parent table) has a column 'type', table y has a foreign key from table x, table z has a foreign key from table x.

I need to do a DB query that joins the parent table x with table y if only 'type' column in table x has a specific value and joins table z if 'type' column has another value

and at the end get the whole data either from x and y or x and z

I tried to do the following but not working

```
$results = DB::table('x')
            ->join('y', function ($join) {
                $join->on('x.id', '=', 'y.x_id')
                    ->where('x.type','=','val1');
            })
            ->join('z', function ($join) {
                $join->on('x.id', '=', 'z.x_id')
                    ->where('x.type','=','val2');
            })
            ->get();
```

any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: structure of y and z tables are the same?

Comment: @mehriabbasi z has an additional column than y

Comment: if it's possible, please send me your sample tables with data, and expected response

Comment: @mehriabbasi thanks dear, I created two different DB calls, then merged the data and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think your "WHERE" statements should be at the end, after all "JOINS" and have "AND" or "OR" between them, depending on what your goal is. At least this is the way for normal SQL queries.